# Android - savedInstanceState can be restored only in onRestoreInstanceState() not in onCreate()

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner in Android and trying to restore the instance state when changing the orientation.

When I implement the restoration in `onRestoreInstanceState()` method, it works. But when implemented inside `onCreate()` method, it doesn't, as if no restoration is implemented, the `EditText` view appears empty.

The problem is, it seems that the test in `savedInstanceState != null` is not passing.

Here's the code in case of implementation is in `onCreate()`:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
            editText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("test_msg"));
        }
    }

//    This method works as expected.
//    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//       EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
//       editText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("test_msg"));
//    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putString("test_msg", "this is test message");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: You can delete all that code, as the text of an `EditText` widget with a unique ID is automatically saved as part of the saved instance state. My guess is that your code is conflicting with Android's build-in instance state processing.

Comment: I think the reason why its not working for your is because you called savedinstanceState.putString() first, and you should've called the super method. In most cases, you have to call the super method first, so that you dont mess the lifecycle

Comment: @CommonsWare @jeffersonTavares I've tried placing `super.onSaveInstanceState()` at the top. But it does nothing. I think because `saveInstanceState.putString()` has nothing to do with the old text inside `EditText` then I think i have to replace the text of `EditText` that's saved inside the `savedInstanceState`. So if you got a way to do that i'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) it might help you with your question.

In your code what seems to be wrong with it is that you only call
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState) after you put something in the Bundle, try first calling this method and then adding to the Bundle.

Comment: I think it's because of `super.onSaveInstanceState` yes. It reassign the old value of the `EditText`. But still.. placing it at the top does nothing.